# Configuring CI/CD pipeline for Android on Bitrise to run UI tests is throwing error: "Could not find the exported app APK"

Tags: android, continuous-integration, ui-testing, android-instrumentation, bitrise

I am setting up a CI/CD pipeline for the Android Kotlin app on Bitrise. I am configuring my pipeline to run UI tests under `app/src/androidTest` folder.

[image]

I want to run the tests under that folder when the pipeline is built. So I am configuring instrumentation tests on the Bitrise following this article, https://devcenter.bitrise.io/testing/device-testing-for-android/. But when I build my pipeline, Android Build for UI Testing step is throwing the following error.

```
Export APKs:
  Export [ app-debug-androidTest.apk => $BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR/app-debug-androidTest.apk ]
Could not find the exported app APK
|                                                                              |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| x | android-build-for-ui-testing@0 (exit code: 1)
```

I did not change any default variables apart from setting the Variant to Debug and Module to app and Test Type to instrumentation. How can I fix it?